# Meaning of "チャラにする"

Tags: meaning

What does this phrase mean?

Here is the context:

死ぬほど悲しかったりすることを全部チャラにする。

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: 「チャラ」 is rarely found in dictionaries, so I would call this question valid.

Comment: Many thanks to you for answering this in great details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「チャラにする」 is an often-used colloquial/slangy expreession meaning "***to call it even***", "***to forgive a debt***", etc.

The more formal and synonymous phrases would include:

「帳消{ちょうけ}しにする」、「差{さ}し引{ひ}きゼロにする」、「相殺{そうさい}する」, etc.

「チャラ」 by itself means "banter", "wise-cracking", etc.  It is, however, rarely used by itself.

If you are familiar with the word 「おべん**ちゃら**」 which means "flattery", the last part is the word in question.

Without more context, it is difficult to tell exactly what your sentence:

> 「死ぬほど悲しかったりすることを全部チャラにする。」

means, but it would be something along the lines of:

> "(Something/Someone) cancels out all of the things that are so sad that you/someone might die from them."

Comment: The phrase appears in a movie trailor https://youtu.be/KjgWDf5Cubs (at 0.42 min.) It's about a girl adopted by a gay couple. This phrase was spoken my the transgender "mom".